# Number of solutions of an arithmetic function's equation

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification, prime-numbers, graphing-functions, algebraic-curves

Say, an equation is given below
\begin{equation}
2\pi(x) - \pi(2x)=\omega(x)
\end{equation}
 where $x$ is a positive integer, $\pi(x)$ is the prime-counting function, and $\omega(x)$ is the number of distinct prime factors of $x$.  I would like to know if this equation holds for finitely many values of $x$ or infinitely many.

If one uses asymptotic formula (from number theory) it can be written that
\begin{equation}
\omega(x) \sim \ln x / \ln \ln(x)
\end{equation}
(from http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~hildebr/ant/main3.pdf)
 and 
\begin{equation}
\pi(x) \sim x/\ln(x),
\end{equation}
so the above equation can be rewritten (after simplification) as
\begin{equation}
2x\ln(2)=\ln(x)\ln\ln(x)\ln(2x) +f(x)
\end{equation}
 where $f(x)$ is an error term.

If  I plot left side (which is linear, supposed to be a straight line) and right side(a curve),assuming $ f(x) $ is 100% accurate, then the equation implies(?!) that the right will intersect left side. Since line can intersect a curve ($ln  $ function) finite times, so there are finite intersection point. So, can I say that there are only finitely many values of $x$?

graph example-
[image]

here f(x) is assumed as x + sinx

without the f(x)-
[image]

Comment: Are these the number-theoretic $\omega$ and $\pi$ or just random functions?  If the former, then $\omega(x) \sim \ln\ln x$ is very false.  In either case, your question is not clear, and your solution is incoherent.  Please edit.

Comment: "\begin{equation}
\omega(x) \sim \ln \ln(x)
\end{equation} is very false "                                                                                                                                                                                 ,check below link-

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DistinctPrimeFactors.html

Comment: To all who put on hold this question- the question is as clear as it could be, I wanted to know whether x has finite integer values for such equation or not. I gave my idea(which might be wrong). It would be helpful if any of you ask which part you did not understand.

Comment: You are entirely misinterpreting the MathWorld page: the average order (also the normal order) of $\omega(x)$ is $\ln \ln x$.  But there are infinitely many values of $x$ for which $\omega(x)$ is far away from $\ln \ln x$, for instance primes and powers of $2$.  It is absolutely not true that $\omega(x)$ is asymptotic to $\ln \ln x$.

Comment: I've reworded your question to fix grammatical errors.  I'd say two things remain unclear: 1) Your $\Rightarrow$ looks like shorthand for some unspoken logic, but I can't guess what you mean.  2) Exactly which curve(s) are you referring to when you talk about intersections? (and what on earth does it have to do with fifth-degree polynomials?)

Comment: 1. so I can't write  \begin{equation}
\ 2x\ln(2)\ll\ln(x)\ln\ln(x)\ln(2x)
\end{equation} from                                 
\begin{equation}
2x\ln(2)=\ln(x)\ln\ln(x)\ln(2x) +f(x)
\end{equation}?? 2. if I plot left side (which is linear, supposed to be a straight line) and right side(a curve),assuming f(x) is 100% accurate, then the equation implies(?!) that the right will intersect  left side. Since line can intersect a curve finite times, so there are finite intersection point, wrong??

Comment: 3. this link - http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~hildebr/ant/main3.pdf  , on page 93, says w(x) has an asymptotic formula like prime counting function(actually derives from prime counting function ) , in this case, the left hand side of the equation will be curve . Are you saying that there is no asymptotic formula for w(x) like prime counting function??

Comment: Both references you provided say explicitly that $\omega(x)$ can be as large as $\ln x / \ln \ln x$.  It can also be as small as $1$ for arbitrarily large $x$.  What do you conclude?

Comment: write \begin{equation}\omega(x)=\ln x /  \ln \ln(x) +g(x)\end{equation} where g(x) is an error term,if g(x) is accurate(which is not at the moment) then the above equation can be used as a formula which gives exact number of distinct prime factor.      What about point 1 and 2 in previous comment ?? are they wrong??

Comment: I have said what my idea is. I might be wrong. But it would be kind of you( the experienced members)to tell exactly why I am wrong rather than  holding the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your proof is wrong, as Erick Wong has explained. Here is a proof of your assertion:

The function $2\pi(x)-\pi(2x)$ is asymptotic to $2x\log 2/\log^2x$ by the Prime Number Theorem (as proved with a stronger error term than just $\sim$). $\omega(n)$ has maximal order $\log n/\log\log n$ on the primorials, and
$$
\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{2n\log 2/\log^2n}{\log n/\log\log n}=+\infty.
$$

As a result there can be only finitely many solutions $2\pi(n)-\pi(2n)=\omega(n).$

Comment: you mean infinitely many solutions??. you are using a "stronger error term",where I have written about an accurate(100%) "error term" function, in this case, both $\pi(x)$ , $\omega(x)$ would provide the exact number and f(x) is obtained from those terms. I claim whatever term f(x) has, it would not change the curve of LEFT HAND SIDE of the equation. what is wrong about this idea??

Comment: @jim198810: If all you know is that $\pi(n)\sim n/\log n$ you can't derive $2\pi(n)-\pi(2n)\sim 2n\log2/\log^2n.$ You need to know more, e.g., $\pi(n)=\operatorname{li}(n)+O(ne^{-a\sqrt{\log n}})$ for some $a>0.$

Comment: Otherwise, you can't show that $f(n)>0$ for large enough $n$.

Comment: I am not interested to know whether f(n) is< or> 0 ( it is not 0) , i would  rather like to know what kind of curve it can produce. Does it create a curve that intersect a line  infinite times when added to ln function?

Comment: I just noticed you proved what I wanted !! .. I woul not say "wrong", it was informal. But my statement is right anyway.

Comment: @jim198810: Your proof is wrong, but the statement you tried to prove is correct. I thought it might be useful to show a correct proof.

Comment: @daniel: The proof is in my answer above. (That's all my answer gives -- I don't point out the mistakes in the original proof since Erick did that already.)

Comment: @Charles ,it was useful, thanks.

Comment: @daniel: I can type it up if you like, but it's just basic algebra, nothing fancy.

Comment: Charles, thanks it's not necessary.

Answer (score 4):

List of errors:

1. The question is about arithmetic functions.  It doesn't make much sense to talk about asymptotic functions.
2. $\omega(x)$ is **not** asymptotic to $\ln \ln x$.  While this does hold on a set of full density, there are still infinitely many counterexamples and you can't ignore them if your question is whether there are infinitely many solutions. In particular, $\omega(x)$ grows as large as $\ln x/\ln \ln x$ when $x$ is a primorial and as small as $1$ when $x$ is a prime power.
3. Your error term $f(x)$ is actually very large so neglecting it completely invalidates your later analysis ($f(x)$ may itself be larger than $2x$).  The fact that $2x \ln 2$ has only finitely many intersections with $\ln x \ln \ln x \ln 2x$ has no bearing on the actual question.
4. In the comments you write "Since line can intersect a curve finite times...".  This is false.  Take the curve $x + \sin x$ and the line $x$.

Comment: 1.Should not use "asymptotic function", have changed. 2. is there any asymptotic formula for w(x) ?? I thought
ω(x) ~ lnx/lnln(x)
is an asymptotic formula for all x. 3.I am not neglecting f(x), it does not matter how big or small it is , the right side will remain a curve. 4. I was talking about ln function, not a sin or cos.

Comment: @jim198810 2. $\omega(x)$ is not asymptotic to any smoothly increasing function.  3. It absolutely does matter how large $f(x)$ is:  Just change the LHS to $2x \ln 2 + 2x \sin x$.  4. You need to define what you mean by "curve": there are many curves that intersect infinitely many times with a line.

Comment: your nice little example also has finite intersection!! but it was just an example... "there are many curves that intersect infinitely many times with a line."- little more information  would help to understand. thanks for being patient!!

Comment: @jim198810 My example has infinite intersections, but I didn't state it explicitly and you seem to have misinterpreted it (certainly you did not graph the functions I suggested).  As I said before in the comments, the curve $x + \sin x$ intersects the line $x$ infinitely many times.  You need to be very specific about what sort of curve you're talking about: originally it sounded like you meant algebraic curve, in which case this is true but totally irrelevant to transcendental functions like $\ln x$ and $\sin x$.

Comment: I thought I can relate algebraic curve , arithmetic function  and interpret, seems "little learning is a..", can you suggest any reading material you think I need to read regarding the problem to overcome weakness ? thanks for being patient.